# How to start Derby server on the specified port by java

Tags: java, sockets, derby

I tried to test Derby sample source code. Unfortunately it failed: [Cannot connect Derby database: connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599374/cannot-connect-derby-database-connection-refused?noredirect=1#comment56945049_34599374)

I was told that I haven't started a server. Official tutorial:

1. Doesn't start any server.I have no feedback after `C:\Apache\db-derby-10.4.1.3-bin\lib> java -jar derbyrun.jar server start` just empty line shows and the `derbyrun.jar` ends.

   2. Doesn't show how to create server on the specified port

My question is: How to start a server on the specified port so the posted code works:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;


public class Restaurants
{
    private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1526/myDB;create=true;user=me;password=mine";
    private static String tableName = "restaurants";
    // jdbc Connection
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        createConnection();
        insertRestaurants(5, "LaVals", "Berkeley");
        selectRestaurants();
        shutdown();
    }

    private static void createConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void insertRestaurants(int id, String restName, String cityName)
    {
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("insert into " + tableName + " values (" +
                    id + ",'" + restName + "','" + cityName +"')");
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void selectRestaurants()
    {
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = results.getMetaData();
            int numberCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i=1; i<=numberCols; i++)
            {
                //print Column Names
                System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)+"\t\t");  
            }

            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

            while(results.next())
            {
                int id = results.getInt(1);
                String restName = results.getString(2);
                String cityName = results.getString(3);
                System.out.println(id + "\t\t" + restName + "\t\t" + cityName);
            }
            results.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void shutdown()
    {
        try
        {
            if (stmt != null)
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
            {
                DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
                conn.close();
            }           
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the server actually running after you type C:\Apache\db-derby-10.4.1.3-bin\lib> java -jar derbyrun.jar server start ? Can you find the process?

Comment: @ozborn No it doesn't run. The program runs for very short while.

Comment: Is there an error log somewhere? You should see something like: Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy. Apache Derby Network Server - 10.4.1.3 - (648739) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527 at 2008-04-28 17:13:13.921 GMT

Comment: @ozborn There is only single empty line then the command prompt shows again in the next line.

Comment: Can you find derby.log  (the error log) ?

Comment: Not sure if you pasted your literal code or not, but you're asking to connect to the server running on 'localhost:1526', but the default port if you don't specify -p when starting the server is 1527.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Same thing was for `1527`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting port numbers

By default, Derby using the Network Server listens on TCP/IP port number 1527. If you want to use a different port number, you can specify it on the command line when starting the Network Server. For example:

```
java org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start -p 1088
```

However, it is better to specify the port numbers by using any of the following methods

```
1. Change the startNetworkServer.bat or startNetworkServer.ksh scripts
2. Use the derby.drda.portNumber property in derby.properties
```

Please refer to:

https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/adminguide/tadminappssettingportnumbers.html